# css3 y offset when using translateZ

Tags: html, css

I currently working on a site with some 3d effects but i have Problems with the things i translate on the Z axis because all of them have diverent Offsets from there parent div.

Here is a sammple i have made. (tested in ff and chrome)

[https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/.......3d.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48465231/HTML3DTestScene/3d.html)

In this sample you can see that the green grid becomes a higher y offset from the parent (orange grid) the lower the parents position is on the page.

is there a work around to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript function that sets a perspective on the container element.

To create a real 3D experience, you need to set a perspective, that distorts the dimensions in a way to recreate the real 3D world.

If you want instead to have "fixed" (or linear) dimensions, just disable that .

Comment: thx a lot


some of my users felt queasy while reading text on the 3d page so I have to something else....


hm ok, I removed the perspective maybe a orthographic look is better readable.